# Multiple line text beside a button without using float

Tags: html, css

I want to display some text beside a big button in multiples lines without using float.

This is my code

```
<div>
    <button>Boton</button>
    <p>asasd asd asdasdas dsadasdas dasd sdsfasdasd sadsadas da sdasdasdasd asdasdasdasd dassda sdasdasd</p>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
div{
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}

button{
    height: 200px;
}

p{
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbZB2/

I want to see something like this
http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8343/capturaft.jpg

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add some widths and try using `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbZB2/1/)

Note: inline-block is not supported in IE7 and earlier so be careful.
For older IE versions you can use `*display:inline;zoom:1;`

Answer (score 1):

This is about the same as the above - But I did clean it up a bit - Just in case you want it styled like in the example. Good luck!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lloanalas/wJFwr/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="example">
    <button>Button</button>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.example {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}
p, button {
    display:inline-block;
}
button {
    width:140px;
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
p {
    width:200px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding:5px;
}
```